# How to extends a TimberPost

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

Probably it is something obvious and has escaped under my nose.

I did not understand how to hook my extended class to timber.

Let's take the example of the **issues**. How can I get an object like `MySitePost` when I call `Timber::query_post()`?

> So now I’ve got an easy way to refer to the `{{ post.issue }}` in our twig templates.
>   Looks like an automatic process... but I'm not so sure about this!

For reference:
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is a good question that might not be so obvious.

To use your custom post, you’ll often find a parameter when fetching posts where you can pass the name of your custom class. The returned object will then be instances of your custom class.

```
$posts = Timber::get_posts( $your_args, 'MySitePost' );
$posts = new Timber\PostQuery( $your_args, 'MySitePost' );
```

When you want to fetch a single post, it works quite similar. You can either directly instantiate your post or pass your post class to the function.

```
$post = new MySitePost();
$post = Timber::get_post( $post_id, 'MySitePost' );
```

If you want to set a default class to be used for your posts, you can use the `Timber\PostClassMap` filter:

```
// Use one class for all Timber posts.
add_filter( 'Timber\PostClassMap', function( $post_class, $post_type ) {
   return 'MySitePost';
}, 10, 2 );

// Use default class for all post types, except for pages.
add_filter( 'Timber\PostClassMap', function( $post_class, $post_type ) {
   // Bailout if not a page
   if ( 'page' !== $post_type ) {
       return $post_class;
   }

   return 'MySitePost';
}, 10, 2 );

// Use a class map for different post types
add_filter( 'Timber\PostClassMap', function( $post_class, $post_type ) {
   return array(
       'post'      => 'MySitePost',
       'apartment' => 'MyApartmentPost',
       'city'      => 'MyCityPost',
   );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working!
I've really missed that function argument. 
There is no way to set a class as default?

Comment: Oh yes there is, using the `Timber\PostClassMap` filter. I’ve added some examples for how it works.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the examples. This will semplify my theme.

Comment: After a fiew Test I have seen that even my `$post` variable is `\Timber\Post` class type. Even if the Timber built in method `get_post_class()` return my custom post type class.
This is how I populate my `$post` variable.

`$context = Timber::get_context();$post = Timber::query_post();$context['post'] =$post;`

Any Idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check the second code example in my answer. `Timber::query_post()` is rarely used anymore. You can either instantiate your custom post class directly or pass it as the second parameter in `Timber::get_post()`.